# Question regarding differentiability of a function on a closed interval versus at a point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently new to Calculus and i'm really confused about the differentiability of a function. Especially when it comes to differentiability on a closed interval versus at a point.

So suppose I have a function $f(x)=3x+1$ at $x$ in [-3,2]. Outside of its domain, the function is not defined.

What i could inferred from the textbook is that, $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval [-3,2], because it is differentiable on (-3,2) and is respectively right-sided and left-sided differentiable on -3 and 2.

But then, what could I say about its differentiability on the point -3 and 2? As the textbook defined, for the function to be differentiable on a point c, $f'(c+)$ must be equal to $f'(c-)$. From that, I could say that the function is not differentiable at points -3 and 2 because the $f'(3-)$ and $f'(2+)$ does not exist.

So now am I able to conclude that $f(x)$ is differentiable on [-3,2] but not at the two points -3 and 2 themselves? Is this contradicting each others?

I really appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Well, this is an ugliness that you have to live with if you choose to define the concept “differentiable on a closed interval”...